# Conflicto entre GridViewScroll y Loading image en ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Actualmente desarrollo en `asp.net c#` , `html5`, `javascript`, `css`.

honestamente no soy muy bueno en javascript e intento resolver asuntos investigando.

Bien, tengo una pagina aspx, la cual muestra una grid, pero esta grid le he congelado la primera columna y la primera fila. todo esto funciona perfectamente bien, el ejemplo lo tome de: `gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw`

Este es el script que utilizo en mi proyecto
http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Scripts/gridviewScroll.min.js?20130319

Por otro lado, he querido implementar un *loading image* el cual me funciona pero me interrumpe el grid, lo quiebra, me aparece sin el freeze y fuera de marco. he tratado muchas formas, en la cual concluí que estos dos señores me generan un conflicto, este es un `jquery` el cual me ayuda en el *loading image*.

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

Hay alguna forma en la cual me puedan ayudar, tal vez seleccionando lo justo y necesario del javascript para que cargue el `loading image`, el ejemplo del `loading image` lo tome de aquí:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-loading-image-while-PostBack-calls-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Podrías poner el código de lo que intentaste?.
Cargas el script de jquery-ui?
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: Estaría bien que incluyeras parte de tu código Javascript y una captura de pantalla y que revisaras si tienes algún error de Javascript. En teoría deberían de convivir los dos scripts pero en WebForms hay que usar jQuery con mucho cuidado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando jquery junto a eventos de asp.net, esa combinación nunca se llevaron bien.
Si la idea es usar eventos podria ayudarte con los controles de ajax toolkit, como ser `UpdateProgress`

[[How Do I:] Use the ASP.NET AJAX UpdateProgress Control?](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-updateprogress-control)

Debo comentarte que jquery y asp.net con sus eventos no se llevan bien, deberias evaluar evitar usar eventos y realizar las operaciones mediante ajax, si usas jquery podrias implementar el `$.ajax` para invocar algun webmethod definido en el `aspx`

saludos

Answer (score 1):

He realizado una pequeña prueba (me intrigaba la librería `GridViewScroll` porque no la conocía) y a mi me ha funcionado correctamente.

[image: GridViewScroll & Loader]

Creo que el problema no está en una incompatibilidad entre `GridViewScroll` y la imagen de cargando. Es posible que sea esta última la que causa problemas con tu diseño.

Aquí dejo un fragmento de mi código (lo tienes completo en [este](https://gist.github.com/rsciriano/bf1332cac4aa058c8857) GitHub Gist)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
<div class="loading" align="center">
    Loading. Please wait.<br /><br />
    <img src="Content/Images/loader.gif" alt="" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Scripts/gridviewScroll.min.js?20130319"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        gridviewScroll();

        $('form').live("submit", function () {
            ShowProgress();
        });
    }); 
    function gridviewScroll() { 
        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({ 
            width: 400, 
            height: 200, 
            freezesize: 1 
        }); 
    } 
    function ShowProgress() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

lo primero que te recomiendo es que verifiques si se está generando algún error javascript, en cuyo caso sería bueno que lo colocaras aquí para poder identificar mejor el caso.

Por otra parte, te recomiendo una excelente librería jQuery que he utilizado en varios proyectos para mostrar un “loading” mientras se realizan procesos en una página: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/ en los ejemplos puedes ver que puedes poner el loading a nivel de toda la página o a nivel de un elemento según tus necesidades.

Saludos.